# How to sum counted rows if same source id

Tags: mysql, sql

Good Day,

I was creating a function where a user can share a post and other users may "LIKE or Comment" on it..

now on my POST table I have "id" and "source_id"  + other details, to track people who like a post I created a table dedicated for like details. with columns: ID, USER_ID ( id of use who liked the post ), post_id

posts table:

```
id | source_id | caption
1        1       original post
2        1       share from id: 1 posts
3        3       new posts
4        4       new posts
```

likes table:

```
id | post_id | user_id
1       1        2
2       1        10
3       2        11
4       2        4
5       2        20
6       3        11
7       4        19
8       4        10
```

in order to count the number of like for a post, I do

```
SELECT  a.id, a.source_id,b.num_likes 
FROM posts AS a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS 
         num_likes,post_id 
             FROM post_likes GROUP BY post_id ) AS b 
ON b.post_id= a.id
WHERE b.num_likes != 0
```

result:

```
id | source_id | num_likes
1        1          2          <--- original post
2        1          3          <--- shared post who also got likes
3        3          1           
4        4          2
```

what I would like to achieve is like these

```
id | source_id   | num_likes
1         1           5              
3         3           1
4         4           2
```

is this possible to achieve by just a query ? if so, could you please help me achieve this..

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUM function to get the total likes.

```
SELECT  min(a.id) as id, a.source_id,sum(b.num_likes) as num_likes 
FROM posts AS a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(1) AS 
         num_likes,post_id 
            FROM post_likes GROUP BY post_id ) AS b 
ON b.post_id= a.id
WHERE b.num_likes != 0
GROUP BY a.source_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can join the tables directly.

```
SELECT MIN(a.id), a.source_id, COUNT(b.num_likes) FROM posts AS a 
LEFT JOIN post_likes AS b ON b.post_id= a.id
GROUP BY a.source_id
HAVING b.num_likes > 0
```

Might need to use a `MIN` for a.id since it is not aggregated. It would depend on your data and use case.

Comment: I copy and paste and it is not working. you should test it before posting.